# Equation label in math preview in Lyx

Tags: equations, lyx

When I turn on instant preview, equations with labels will compile to something messed up, e.g.

[image]

The Lyx code looks fine.

[image]

Is this the intended behavior of instant preview with equation label? If not, how do I resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably not 'intended' in the sense that people specifically wanted this overprinting behaviour, but it may be hard to get a better result if the equation is very long, the equation number on the left and the label helpfully shown there as well. In general I would say issues like this should be reported to the developers directly. Or is your question how to suppress the label info (the `eqn:NTKparam` bit in the first picture)?

Comment: I played around with LyX for a bit, but was not able to reproduce this specific overprinting behaviour. You may want to add a step-by-step recipe to reproduce the output you are getting, so other people have a chance of playing around with it as well.

Comment: perhaps one of these bug reports is related: https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10573 and https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/6190

Comment: @scottkosty Yes those bug reports reflect the same issues. The latter report suggested passing in "reqno" as a document class option, which solves the issue for me.

Comment: @SorcererofDM Great! Would you mind uploading a .lyx minimal example on the bug report? Also, could you leave comments on the tickets describing the relationship between the two? If they are duplicates, we should close one. If they're not, we should at least reference the other and explain the connection (currently they do not even mention the other).

Comment: It looks like the `showlabels` package is in operation here.  That wouldn't be true for a final version, so after everything has been checked, `\showlabels` should be removed and the equation numbers can be restored to the left.  (Until then, however, it does appear to be a bug that should be fixed.)

Comment: @scottkosty when I create a new document to replicate this, the math preview doesn't work anymore, even though it still works in my main document that I was editing.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I did not manually add a `showlabels` package. Is that on by default in lyx?

Comment: I don't know whether lyx automatically provides `showlabels`, but that is generally what they look like.  (I made a guess.)

Comment: document to replicate this, the math preview doesn't work anymore, even though it still works in my main document @SorcererofDM it might be because you define new commands in your preamble so I guess those would need to be copied over to the new document.

Answer (score 1):

@scottkosty mentions 2 relevant bug reports [1](http://lyx.org/trac/ticket/10573) and [2](http://lyx.org/trac/ticket/6190), and the latter suggested passing in "reqno" as a document class option. This changes the equation labeling to the right side (instead of the left as shown) and avoids overlapping the equation label with the equation. Since I'm OK with right side equation label, this solves the issue for me.

[image]